# Increase spacing between equations

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{Concentration of unknown sample solution} &= \frac{303 - 0.00227}{0.215} \\
&= 1.400 \si{\mg \per \L}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to have a line break like this?

```
concentration of unknown =
    sample solution
```

And increase the spacing between the equations?

Comment: It should be `\SI{1.400}{\mg\per\L}`

Comment: @egreg So that's why my units were touching the numbers. I thought it was meant to be like that.

Comment: A thin space should separate the number from the unit, which is what `\SI` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\parbox{5cm}{\centering Concentration of unknown sample solution} 
&= \frac{303 - 0.00227}{0.215} \\[\jot]
&= \SI{1.400}{\mg \per \L}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `varwidth` or `tabular` instead of `\parbox`?